# port undefined run by npm run start

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, port, nodemon

I write following code in nodeJS :

```
const port = process.env.port;
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
app.use('/', routes);
app.listen(port, console.log('your browser run on port ' + port));
```

when  i run code by nodemon(npm run start), port variable is undefined while when i run it with node(node app.js), the port variable contains the value of the port where the program is running. Why the program run by nodemon the  value of the port variable is undefined?

Comment: Where are you setting `process.env.port`? Generally env vars are uppercase, i.e. `process.env.PORT` but it depends on your setup.

Comment: what does that mean *the value of the port where the program is running*? The program is not running yet.

Answer (score 1):

Export the port beforehand.

```sh
export port=8080
```

Additionally, use some fallback.

```js
const port = process.env.port || "3000"
```

Also note, by convention, environment variables are upper cases.

```sh
export APP_PORT=8080
```

```js
const port = process.env.APP_PORT || "3000"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have .env file create one.
Write the port value in

`port=8080`

install the dotenv from npm

```
npm install dotenv
```

add the this line before define port variable

```
require('dotenv').config()
```